# achartengine a background color field defining particular values

Tags: colors, background, field, achartengine

I have this graph made with achartengine library:

[image: my_scatter_graph]
a------------------------

What I want to do is to have a color field in it between particular values, like that:

[image: scatter_graph_with_color_field]

Some of my code:

```
protected void setRenderer(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, int[] colors,
        PointStyle[] styles) {
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    renderer.setPointSize(2f);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 20 });
    int length = colors.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(colors[i]);
        r.setPointStyle(styles[i]);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }
}
```

I really dont know how to do that. Is there a way, how to accomplish that?
Any help appreciated.
Jan

Comment: Is there any documentation on the achartengine library? I found only some very brief tutorials.

Comment: There are tutorials and there is also the javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a scatter chart defined. You could do a combined XY chart which would include the current scatter chart and an extra range bar chart that would actually build the colored rectangle you need.

An example for building a combined XY chart is available [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/CombinedTemperatureChart.java).

Comment: I assume there is not a simple way, how to do that, so thank you.. might try like that later!